# Is it possible to track file pointer (document position) with XML API?

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax, file-pointer

I want to index XML file by IDs of its main level entries. I plan to parse entire document, extract ID from entry and index it (remember file position of opening tag `<` and position of closing tag `>` + 1). Later this will allow me to find this place fast by ID.

But is it possible to track file position with SAX?

If it is not possible with SAX, then is there any other parser capable of it?

**UPDATE**

I found that [Location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/Location.html) has `getCharacterOffset()` method. Is it of `StAX`?

**UPDATE 2**

`Location` works but somehow unexpected. The first tag is `mediawiki` and it starts from position zero. Simultaneously `getCharacterOffset()` returns 4 from the very beginning of processing.

Looks like some read aheads occur.

Comment: Not with the abstractions present in the standard Java APIs, as far as I know.